# Hyperlink in mail is recognized as plain text, not as a link

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, sendmail

I have an C# app, which gets the mail informations like To, subject, message. Then it calls the wcf service to send a mail(intern it uses smtpclient.send()). The issue is, when the message body contains hyperlink, it is not regonized as a link. It sends as a plain text.

This has 2 scenario's,

1. http://localhost/**my%20pages**/test.aspx - not recognized as a link
2. http://localhost/**mypages**/test.aspx - recognized as a link

But both the mail property is plain text. I am using the HttpUtility.UrlEncode(), to encode the link.

how to solve this issue?

Thanx in advance

Comment: When you say that "localhost/my%20pages/test.aspx" is not recognized as a link, do you mean only the first part is recognized by the mail client, or do you really meany that none of it is recognized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the email as HTML if you want to ensure URLs are links - you will need to format it as HTML.

Plain text will not magically create links for you, though *some* email clients will see a `http` prefix and automatically create a link from it, whether the source was text or not (Outlook for example).

Answer (score 0):

As you mention yourself, "normal" links in your plain-text mails get recognized but links containing %20 -- i.e. a blank character -- aren't. One solution is to make sure you avoid %20 blanks in URLs in the first place, as (even though perfectly legal) it is not a very "friendly" character in a URL to begin with. You could, if you want to, map a special more friendly character (say, a triple dash ---) to a blank later on using htaccess.